# change job type of an executed ansible tower job from check to run upon rerun

Tags: ansible, continuous-deployment, ansible-template, ansible-tower

In the continuous delivery step of my application, I want Jenkins to invoke the ansible tower job (through tower cli) in job type check.

Once the devops team decides to release it, I want them to just change the job type to "run" so that the actual deployment can take place. The idea is to preserve the extra-args like version of the artifact that Jenkins built and avoid devops team from manually copying them to other job template.

In ansible tower, I don't see an an option to edit the executed check job to a run job type. Is there a better way to "cache" the deployment info in tower for deployment at later time?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of Ansible Tower you're using.  I believe that Tower < 3.0 doesn't support specifying the job type as a build parameter.  You'd have to create 2 job templates (one with job type = check and one with job type = run).

If you're using Tower >= 3.0, here's the `tower-cli` command.

```
tower-cli job launch --job-type check --job-template=###
```

**EDIT:** Make sure that your job template has the "Prompt on launch" option check marked under "JOB TYPE"

Comment: What if the job template has already run as a check job? is there a way to rerun it as a "run" job

Comment: Look at my answer a bit closer.  If your tower version is < 3.0 you can't rerun the same template as a "run" job - you'll need to create a separate template and use that instead.  Otherwise if you're using >= 3.0 you can set the job type to "run" using `--job-type run` as a flag in your `tower-cli` command.